# How to scrollIndex bottom on iOS in android it's working

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

how can I achieve scrollIndex on iOS? I tried following code:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:'Row #50'
});



var tableData = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    tableData.push(
        {title:'Row #'+i}
    );
}



var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data:tableData
});
table.scrollToIndex(table.data[0].rows.length, Titanium.UI.iOS.TableViewScrollPosition.TOP);

win.add(table);

win.open();
```

How it will work?

Answer (score 1):

invalide index, do this

```
table.scrollToIndex(table.data[0].rows.length - 1, Titanium.UI.iOS.TableViewScrollPosition.TOP);
```